# What is Fourier transform of $|(x,t)|^{-\alpha}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let the $x\in \mathbb{R}^d, t\in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $(x,t)\in {\mathbb{R^{d+1}}}$.

I already know the Fourier transform of $|x|^{-\alpha}$ is $|\xi|^{-d+\alpha}$.

How do I get the Fourier transform of $|(x,t)|^{-\alpha} = \left(\sqrt{|x|^2 +t^2}\right)^{-\alpha}$ with respect to $x$ ?

Comment: @reuns Isn't there the more general form of that?

Comment: I meant the inverse Fourier transform of $|(y,u)|^{\alpha-d-1}$ in $u \in \mathbb{R}$ (and $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ fixed).

Comment: If $\alpha > d - 1$ and $t > 0$, so that the Fourier integral exists,
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d} (|\boldsymbol x|^2 + t^2)^{-\alpha/2}
 e^{i \boldsymbol x \cdot \boldsymbol \xi} d\boldsymbol x =
\frac
 {2^{\mu + 1} \hspace{1px} \pi^{d/2} \hspace{1px} t^\mu}
 {\Gamma {\left( \frac \alpha 2 \right)}}
|\boldsymbol \xi|^{-\mu} K_\mu(t \hspace{1px} |\boldsymbol \xi|),$$
where $\mu = (d - \alpha)/2$ and $K$ is the Bessel function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interested in obtaining an explicit expression for
$$I(k,t) =\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \int\left(\sqrt{|x|^2 +t^2}\right)^{-\alpha} e^{i x\cdot k} d^n x\,.$$
Let us introduce [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) with the first coordinate of $x$ with component $r \cos \phi$ pointing along $k$. We thus reduce the integral to the form
$$I(k,t) =\frac{S_{n-2}}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \int_0^\infty \int_{0}^\pi r^{n-1}\left(\sqrt{r^2 +t^2}\right)^{-\alpha} e^{i r |k| \cos(\phi)} \sin^{n-2}(\phi)\,d\phi dr $$
where $S_n$ is the surface area of the $n$-sphere given by
$$ S_{n-1} =\frac{n\pi^\frac{n}{2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1 \right)}.$$

The integral over $\phi$ can be easily executed with the result
$$I(k,t) =\frac{S_{n-2}}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \int_0^\infty \frac{\pi r^{n-1} J_{n/2-1}(r |k|)}{(r^2+t^2)^{\alpha/2}} dr\,. $$
I am not sure about the remaining integral. Maybe somebody has an idea...

Comment: It is also $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty (r^2+u^2)^c \cos(ut)du, c =( \alpha-d-1)/2,r=|x|$

Comment: If $x_1 = r \cos \phi$, then I believe the Jacobian should depend on $\phi$. The integrand will contain a factor of $\sin^{n - 2} \phi$, giving $J_{n/2 - 1}(r |k|)$.

Comment: Thanks Maxim for spotting that, I will correct...